# Collision detection in kinematic bodies LIBGDX

Tags: java, box2d, collision-detection, libgdx

I managed to use box2d in libgdx. However the example code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453176/how-to-use-the-libgdx-contactlistener) is for dynamic body only. I tried to use it and it works great but when i change the Dynamic to KinematicBody the code does not work. here is my code

```
    @Override
        public void create() {
      // Create our body definition
            BodyDef groundBodyDef =new BodyDef();
            groundBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    // Set its world position
            groundBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, 10));

    // Create a body from the defintion and add it to the world
             groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);

    // Create a polygon shape
            PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
    // Set the polygon shape as a box which is twice the size of our view port and 20 high
    // (setAsBox takes half-width and half-height as arguments)
            groundBox.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth, 10.0f);
    // Create a fixture from our polygon shape and add it to our ground body
            groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f);
    // Clean up after ourselves
            groundBox.dispose();

            //endregion


            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    // We set our body to dynamic, for something like ground which doesnt move we would set it to StaticBody
            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;
    // Set our body's starting position in the world
            bodyDef.position.set(bolaX, bolaY);

    // Create our body in the world using our body definition
             body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
            CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
            circle.setRadius(20f);


    // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
            FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = circle;
            fixtureDef.density = 20;

            fixtureDef.friction = 0;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f; // Make it bounce a little bit

    // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
            Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    // Remember to dispose of any shapes after you're done with them!
    // BodyDef and FixtureDef don't need disposing, but shapes do.
            circle.dispose();

            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }



     @Override
        public void render() {


            world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);



            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            camera.update();



            //batch.getProjectionMatrix().set(camera.combined);
            batch.begin();
            textureBodies = body.getPosition();
            float angle = MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * body.getAngle();
            //batch.draw(ball,textureBodies.x ,textureBodies.y  );
            batch.draw(ball, textureBodies.x - (bola.getWidth() / 2) , textureBodies.y - (bola.getHeight()/2) , // the bottom left corner of the box, unrotated
                    1f, 1f, // the rotation center relative to the bottom left corner of the box
                    bola.getWidth(), bola.getHeight(), // the width and height of the box
                    1, 1, // the scale on the x- and y-axis
                    angle);
            batch.end();

            debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DPAD_UP)){
                    Gdx.app.log("Input Test", "key down: " + "aw ---- x" +  body.getPosition().x + "  y   " + body.getPosition().y);
                    vel += 1;
                    //Gdx.app.log("vel","" + vel);
                    body.setLinearVelocity(0f,vel);
                } else{
                    vel -= 1;
                   // Gdx.app.log("vel","" + body.getPosition().y);
                    body.setLinearVelocity(0f,vel);
                }

  int numContacts = world.getContactCount();
        if (numContacts > 0) {
            Gdx.app.log("contact", "start of contact list");
            for (Contact contact : world.getContactList()) {
                Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
                Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
                Gdx.app.log("contact", "between " + fixtureA.toString() + " and " + fixtureB.toString());
            }
            Gdx.app.log("contact", "end of contact list");
        }


        }
```

And here is the image.. You can see in the left side is the DynamicBody and the right side is the KinematicBody.

[image]

Getting the contacts works on Dynamic Body but not on Kinematic Body. Can you tell how to detect the collision in kinematic body?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kinematic body don't collide with static body.
Maybe this will help you.

Comment: So the use of kinematic is wrong in using for example a moving object on any direction? Because there is no collision on kinematic?

Comment: Well  i didnt said that there is no collision on kinematic body. Kinematic body collide with dynamic bodies. Use of dynamic or kinematic or static body depends on the requirement of game. Generally if a body is moving then i prefer to keep it dynamic.

Comment: @Pranav008 please add reference or more explanation, elaborate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Kinematic Bodies are only influenced by velocities and not by forces
Static bodies have O displacement but are effected by forces i.e. they generate impulse upon collision whereas Dynamic Bodies have both