# How to create a body with Polygon and Rectangle attached together in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, polygon

I am a newbie in Libgdx. I am working on detecting collisions for two bodies. Have created two bodies using "polygonshape" but unfortunately there isn't any method to detect collision among "PolygonShapes" but for "rectangles" .So I came up with an idea of attaching the rectangle at the front of each of the polygons and then detect collision for rectangles but when I run the code, I don't see any rectangles but only polygons.

Here is my code,

```
public class Player implements Screen, InputProcessor {

private Body polybody;
private Player player;
private World world;
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;

private Body enemybody;
private Sprite polysprite;
public final float width,height;
private Vector2 movement=new Vector2();
    private float speed=580;


    public Player(World world,float x,float y,float width)
    {
    this.width=width; //IMP
    height=width*2;
    BodyDef polygon=new BodyDef();
    polygon.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
    polygon.position.set(x,y); //
    PolygonShape poly =new PolygonShape();
    poly.setAsBox(width/2,height/2); //
    FixtureDef polyfixture=new FixtureDef();
    polyfixture.shape=poly;

    polyfixture.friction=0.8f;  //
    polyfixture.restitution=0.1f; //
    polyfixture.density=3; //


   //creating actual body
    polybody=world.createBody(polygon);
    polybody.createFixture(polyfixture);

  //disposing the body
    BodyDef rectangle=new BodyDef();
    rectangle.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
    Rectangle rect=new Rectangle();

    rect.setWidth(50);
    rect.setHeight(50);
    rect.setPosition(x, y);
    enemybody=world.createBody(rectangle);

    polysprite=new Sprite(new Texture("img/car.jpg"));
    polysprite.setSize(0.5f, 1); 
    polysprite.setOrigin(polysprite.getWidth()/2, polysprite.getHeight()/2);
    polybody.setUserData(polysprite);
    poly.dispose();   

   }

   public void update()
   {
      polybody.applyForceToCenter(movement, true);
      enemybody.applyForceToCenter(movement,true);

   }


  public Body getBody(){
   {
  return polybody;
   }
  }
}
```

Collision Code:

```
 public Player(World world,float x,float y,float width)
 {
 this.width=width; //IMP
  height=width*2;
 BodyDef polygon=new BodyDef();
 polygon.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
  polygon.position.set(x,y); //

 //   polygon.fixedRotation=true;
 //polygon shape
 //Rectangle poly=new Rectangle();
 PolygonShape poly =new PolygonShape();
 poly.setAsBox(width/2,height/2); //
 //fixture defn
 polygon.position.set(5,4);
 FixtureDef polyfixture=new FixtureDef();
 polyfixture.shape=poly;

 polyfixture.friction=0.8f;  //
  polyfixture.restitution=0.1f; //
 polyfixture.density=3; //


  //creating actual body
  polybody=world.createBody(polygon);
 polybody.createFixture(polyfixture);
 // polybody.applyAngularImpulse(52, true);
 //disposing the body

polysprite=new Sprite(new Texture("img/car.jpg"));

 polysprite.setSize(2, 3); //size of mario
polysprite.setOrigin(polysprite.getWidth()/2, polysprite.getHeight()/2);
 polybody.setUserData(polysprite);
```

//2nd body

```
   BodyDef polygons=new BodyDef();
 polygons.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;

 PolygonShape polys=new PolygonShape();
 polys.setAsBox(2,2);

FixtureDef polyxfixture=new FixtureDef();
polyxfixture.shape=polys;

polyxfixture.friction=0.8f;
polyxfixture.restitution=0.1f;
polyxfixture.density=3;


  polybodys=world.createBody(polygons);
  polybodys.createFixture(polyxfixture);

 poly.dispose();    

  }

   @Override
   public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Fixture fixtureA=contact.getFixtureA();
Fixture fixtureB=contact.getFixtureB();
System.out.println("collides");
 }
```

This is my code. I have created 2 bodies using "polygonshape" and "rectangle" but rectangle isn't created. I can't find what is the mistake. Please help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you are mixing 2 different things: `Rectangle` from the libgdx API and `Body`s from Box2D. `Rectangle` has nothing to do with the Box2D physic engine and therefore it can't detect collisions with your `Rectangle`. Instead you should create a `Fixture` with a Rectangle-Like-Shape, like you allready did for the `polyfixture`. Then add this `Fixture` to your `enemyBody`.

Comment: When I detect collisions among two polygonshapes like if(Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(poly,polys) where poly is"polygonshape" and polys is also "polygonshape" as above ,it gives me error like     The method overlapConvexPolygons(Polygon, Polygon) in the type Intersector is not applicable for the arguments (PolygonShape, PolygonShape) @Springrbua

Comment: I added an answer, which hopefully clears up those things. If you use Box2D, you don't need to detect collisions, box2D does this for you.

Comment: How to detect collisions using box2D . @Springrbua

Comment: I added some information to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are a bit confused and you are mixing two absolutely independend things:

- `Box2D`, a physics engine, which does all physic calculations
  (including collission detection) for you.
- The `Rectangle`, `Polygon` and the `Intersector` class of libgdx.

I try to explain what both of them do and why you can't use them together.
The `Polygonshape` is part of the `Box2D` engine. It is used to give a `Fixture` it's shape, which is then used by the collission detection of `Box2D`.
You can read something about `Box2D` [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d).
The `Rectangle` class is some kind of "Helperclass" in Libgdx, which let you define a `Rectangle`, with a given position, width and height. It can be used together with the `Intersector`class, which provides some usefull methods for collission detection and other things.
There is also a class caled `Polygon`. It is, again, a Libgdx class and can't be mixed with the `Box2D` `PolygonShape`. The Libgdx `Polygon` instead can be used with the `Intersector` class, which provides a method to check for an overlap between 2 `Polygon`s. `Polygon`s are defined by a `float[]`, giving the position of all it's corner points.
That means, that if you want to use the physics engine `Box2D`, you need to work with the `PolygonShape` and other shapes, provided by `Box2D`.
If you instead don't want to use the physics engine and do the collission detection on your own, you can use `Rectangle`, `Polygon` and other shapes from `Libgdx` and you also can use the `Intersector` for overlap-testing.

**EDIT:**
If you take a look at [this link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d), there is a section "Contact Listener". There you can see, that the `ContactListener` provides the methods `beginContact` (called when two objects start to collide/overlap) and `endContact` (called when the contact between the two objects ends).
You need to implement those methods and set it as the `world`s `ContactListener`.
Node, that Box2D automatically handles collisions, by seperating the colliding objects (bounce back). If thats not what you want, you shouldset the `isSensor`-Flag of your `FixtureDef`. That way, Box2D will notify you, that there is a collision (`beginContact` gets called) but won't handle it for you.

**EDIT 2**:
The `Contact` object you get in your `ContactListener`-Methods holds 2 `Fixture`s: `FixtrueA` and `FixtureB`.
Thats because in every contact or collision 2 objects have to be involved, so `FixtureA` is one of them and `FixtureB` is the ther one.
The reason, why a `Contact` contains 2 `Fixture`s instead of 2 `Body`s is the following:
Let's say we have a `Player`, defined by a `Body`. This `Body` contains 2 `Fixture`s: `headFixture`, a circle repressenting it's head and `bodyFixture`, a rectangle, repressenting the hitbox of the `Player`s body and feet.
Now, if a `Bullet` (a `Body` with one `Fixture`) hits our `Player`, it may make a difference, if it hits its body or its head.
So basicly a `Body` repressents our whole object, the `Player`, while the `Fixture`s repressent some parts of it, which are used for the physics-calculation.
If you only want to handle collissions per `Body`, you can get the `Body` by calling `fixtureA().getBody()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. I just had a look for how to implement "contact listener" in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453176/how-to-use-the-libgdx-contactlistener) but I don't understand what fixtureA and fixtureB actually does and what it is @Springrbua

Comment: @Anusha added some more info :)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I have created 2 bodies and tested if it collides but I don't see any changes and I am not sure of what I did is correct with respect to contactlistener .Is FixtureA is the fixture of first body and FixtureB is the fixture of second? @Springrbua

Comment: @Anusha exactly. When, for example, a `Player` collides with a `Bullet`, `FixtureA` would be a `Fixture` of the `Player` (or the `Bullet`) and `FixtureB` a `Fixture` of the other `Body`. You could use the `UserData` of the `Fixture` or the `Body` to detect, which `Body` is the `Player` and which one is the `Bullet`.

Comment: ok sir still I made the body move and collide with the another body and checked using println statement but the body doesn't collide @Springrbua

Comment: It's hard to tell you where the bug is, ithout seeing the code. But i guess you should read the wiki page i linked above and also the Box2D tutorialcs on IForce2D. They will definitely help you understanding how Box2D works.